# Use fenced code blocks in pandoc markdown output

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is there a way to make `pandoc` output fenced code blocks (i.e. using triple backticks) when outputting markdown, rather than indenting with four spaces?

Comment: This is controlled by the [fenced_code_attributes](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_code_attributes) extension, which should be enabled by default. What command are you using to output Markdown?

Comment: Just `pandoc index.html -o index.md`. But I think you've misread. As far as I can see `fenced_code_attributes` enables support for attributes on fenced code blocks when *reading* markdown. It doesn't have anything to do with writing markdown.

Comment: Tann awesomebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use a Lua filter to "manually" create the block output:

````lua
local fenced = '```\n%s\n```\n'
function CodeBlock (cb)
  -- use pandoc's default behavior if the block has classes or attribs
  if cb.classes[1] or next(cb.attributes) then
    return nil
  end
  return pandoc.RawBlock('markdown', fenced:format(cb.text))
end
````

Save the above to a file, then pass the file to pandoc via the `--lua-filter` option.

Comment: Seems that `--lua-filter` is `--filter` now?

Comment: Those are different: `--filter` (or `-F`) expects a JSON filter, i.e., a program that takes pandoc's JSON as input and produces JSON ouput, which is then read back into pandoc. The `--lua-filter` (or `-L`) option needs a Lua filter that is run by the Lua interpreter that's baked into pandoc.

Comment: I see, thank you. My issue was just that my pandoc(1) is so old that I don’t have this option.

Answer (score 0):

For what it’s worth: I used source blocks in Org like:

```
#+begin_src 
select * from universe;
#+end_src
```

These were converted to indented code blocks using:

```
pandoc --from=org --to=markdown --output=output.md input.org
```

But Pandoc switched to fenced blocks if I added `sql` (or `java` or whatever else language):

```
#+begin_src sql
select * from universe;
#+end_src
```

Output:

````
``` {.sql}
select * from universe;
```
````