# Access values of pandoc.Figure elements in pandoc.RawBlock with custom Lua writer

Tags: lua, output, pandoc, figure, writer

To solve my [concrete question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77504584/pandoc-md-latex-write-lua-filter-to-change-latex-macro-used-for-caption) (asked also on the Pandoc mailing list, which, unfortunatley, seems to be down due to spam mails at the moment) regarding using the Latex `\sidecaption` command in a figure element exported to Latex, I'm now trying to understand the processing of Lua writers/filters and especially the accessing of field values for Pandoc more generally.

The main question is, how can I access the values of the [fields of a pandoc.Figure](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-figure) to rearrange them in the output through a custom writer; especially the fields `content` (image), `caption` and `attr`. I checked the pandoc docs and some examples from the web, but couldn't find many maybe due to the overhaul for figures in Pandoc 3.0.

So far I got the following code:

```lua
function Writer (doc, opts)
  local filter = {
     Figure = function (fig)
    local tester = '\\begin{figure*}\n' .. fig.content .. '\n\\end{figure*}\n' -- or/and fig.caption
    return pandoc.RawBlock('latex', tester)
    end
  }
  return pandoc.write(doc:walk(filter), 'latex', opts)
end
```

If I call the writer (together with my custom template) like this `pandoc --template=mytemplate -t test-writer.lua ast-test.txt -o ast-test.tex`, I get the error `bad argument #2 to 'concat' (table expected, got string)` for the line containing the code when called with `fig.content`; and the error `attempt to concatenate a table value (field 'caption')` when called with `fig.caption`; for the latter case I also tried `fig.caption.long` which also results in `(table expected, got string)`.

But when I call it without any `fig.` content, I get an empty `{figure*}` (starred!) Latex environment in the output file without any error messages. Thus, the method seems to work, but I just can't figure out how to access the field values of the Figure block.

The test file ast-test.txt only contains a few lines:

```markdown
---
title: A title
---

# Einleitung

Some text

![caption *to* an image](counter_plot_new_periods.png)
```

**Edit**

I tried an approach using a Lua filter instead of a Lua custom writer (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66982937/19647155) by @tarleb):

```lua
function Figure (elem)
  raw_elem = '\\begin{figure*}\n' ..
              '\\centering\n' .. 
              '\\includegraphics[width=0.9\\textwidth]{' .. elem.content .. '}\n' .. 
              '\\caption{' .. elem.caption .. '}\n' .. 
              '\\end{figure*}'
  return pandoc.RawBlock('latex', raw_elem)
end
```

but get the same error. This version also works if I remove the `elem.(...)` parts and renders the Latex commands correctly in the .tex file. But of course I need the values of the fields from the figure block to get a working Latex document.

**2nd Edit**:

I played around a little bit more and at least got the content of the caption with `pandoc.utils.stringify`:

```lua
Figure = function(elem)
   Caption = pandoc.utils.stringify(elem.caption.long)
   local raw_elem = '\\begin{figure*}\n' .. Caption .. '\n\\end{figure*}'
   return pandoc.RawBlock('latex', raw_elem)
end
```

This outputs the content of `elem.caption.long` but, as mentioned in the docs, erases **all** formatting, thus, also the emphasised "to" in the caption.

Furthermore, this is no solution for the image content of the `Figure` which is a pandoc function on its own, which should be preserved inside the edited `Figure` function...

---

I appreciate any hint how to access those Figure field values correctly in Lua!